# convex optimization problem (convex function and convex set as a constraint)

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

As far as I know, convex optimization problem is defined as a form of
\begin{alignat}{1}
\min_{x \in D} & \quad f(x) \\
\text{subject to} & \quad g(x) \leq 0 \\
                  & \quad h(x) = 0
\end{alignat}
where, $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are convex functions, and $h(x)$ is a affine function.

Here, my question is why $g(x)$ should be a convex function.

In my thought, for example, if $g(x)$ is $(x-2)x^2(x+2) - 4$, even though $g(x)$ is not a convex function, $g(x) \leq 0$ has a convex set as a solution. It means the problem can be a convex optimization problem.

Am I right? or what am I missing?

Comment: You could define a convex optimization problem as minimizing a convex function over a convex set, but it's not clear what should be the dual problem for such a general problem. If our goal is to describe the dual problem construction, then it is helpful to have the problem expressed in the specific form you mentioned.